# Flask web developments passing multiple variables thru app.route

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, flask

what im trying to do today is to pass multiple variables thru links to flask or just additional symbols followed by url
i have tried this

```
@app.route('/?action='+'<cmd>')
```

or

```
@app.route('/?<cmd>')
```

both give me a 404 error

but when i remove the "?" symbol it works fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get query string parameter values the best way is to do this in your `@app.route` function.  For example, getting the `action` query string parameter:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    action = request.args.get('action')
```

Comment: gimme a sec let me try that

Comment: nvm, its working , thanks just forgot the ? sign so 127.0.0.1:5000/?action=login will do the job . thanks alot